# Get all the groups and the permissions they have, on a document library (using SPServices)?

Tags: 2013, document-library, permissions, spservices

I'm trying to figure out how to get a list of all the groups that are allowed to edit/read a document library. I will need the name of each group and which permissions it has (edit or read).

I used SPServices to make an array of all subsites and all document libraries for each subsite. This works just fine, I can get the output in my console. But now I wish to loop through all document libraries and store the permissions per document library in an array. So far with no success. I cannot seem to find a way to see which groups are linked to which library, and which permissions (mostly unique) they have.

Is there such a way? Or is this simply not possible? Because when I check out an individual document library and want to manage its permissions, I can see a list of groups and which permissions each group has on that document library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use the [SiteData service](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SiteData). A basic example:

```
$().SPServices({
      operation: "SiteDataGetList",
      strListName: "Announcements",
      async: false,
      completefunc: function(xData, Status) {}
});
```

This will return a node sListMetadata. If the list inherits permissions it will have an attribute of `<InheritedSecurity>true</InheritedSecurity>`. If the list is using custom permissions, it will have a `<Permissions>` node and give all the permissions.